# ConEmu doesn't find bash commands

Tags: groovy

I recently downloaded ConEmu Linux terminal for running groovy. Installing groovy went well but switching to its environment returns me an error "bash: groovysh: command not found". Is there a way to get those command to the terminal? Installing scoop via Powershell didn't no help unfortunately

Comment: I'd suggest to add the tags beside groovy, that seem responsible for it not to work. Also add how you have installed groovy (e.g. skdman?) and what you or the installer has done to add the install path to the PATH-env-var.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install groovy from the link directly as well as from the terminal and starting the terminal as administrator afterwards. Issue resolved.